# Eclipse error "Could not found android-beacon-library.apk"

Tags: android, beacon

I've developed a Project that uses the android-beacon-library. I have imported the android-beacon-library folder as an existing project in the workspace and then I've done Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add, then selected the imported project. I have no problems using the library apis, but when I debug my app, Console says:

```
[2015-03-10 14:25:01 - android-beacon-library] Could not find android-beacon-library.apk!
```

And then it debugs my app without erros (apparently)... why it says me that it could not find the android-beacon-library.apk?

Answer (score 1):

try importing the android -beaconlibrary file to to libs folder of your application